# How to get data from a form in php mvc

Tags: php, forms, model-view-controller

I'm starting to learn php and mvc and this is what I want to do. I want to create a simple login form. 
My login form is is as follows

```
<html>
<body>
<form action = "index.php" method = "post">
userName : <input type = "text" name = "username"/>
Password : <input type = "text" name = "password"/>
<br/>
<input type = "submit" value = "login" name = "btnlogin"/>
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

, and I have my models and views all set up, but how do I pass this information to the model, my controller class is as follows

```
<?php

class controller
{
public $modelBook;
public $view;
public $modeluser;


function __construct()
{
    $this->modelBook = new Book();
    $this->view = new view();
    $this->modeluser = new members();

    $this->Home();
}

function Home()
{
    $this->view->viewThis('login.php');
}

function login($username,$password)
{
    $data = $this->modeluser->login($username, $password);
    $this->view->viewThis('member.php',$data);
}
```

the login view loads, but how do I get the data in the form to the model using the login function?

EDIT :

my index.php

```
define ('SERVER_ROOT','C:\wamp\www\eclipse\MVCLMS');

define ('SITE_ROOT', 'http://localhost');

require_once 'controller/router.php';

?>
```

my router.php file

```
<?php
include 'model/modelBook.php';
include 'model/modelLogin.php';
include 'view/load.php';
include 'controller/controller.php';

$controller = new controller();
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should have following function in your index.php

```
<?php
   if ($_POST['username'] && $_POST['password'] ) {
      $controller = new controller();
      $controller->login($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);
   }
?>
```

This code place depend on your mvc structure.